# How to fix aws region error "ValueError: Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running sagemaker for the first time from my laptop. When I try to start the session I get this error
ValueError: Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker

Local config is set to eu-west-1 which is supported by Sagemaker.

I changed the region to us-west-2 and back and nothing changed. Of course I restarted the notebook kernel after each change just in case.

```
import boto3

import re

import os

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import sagemaker as sage

boto_session = boto3.Session(profile_name="bennu")

session = sage.Session(boto_session=boto_session) #this is where the error appears
```

I expect the session to start and to move on to the next step. The full notebook is here https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Machine-Learning-Using-Amazon-SageMaker-v-/blob/master/section_1/train_and_deploy_your_first_model_on_sagemaker.ipynb

Comment: What do you mean by running SageMaker from your laptop? Are you running a notebook that should start a training job on SageMaker, or are you running on SageMaker notebook instance?

Comment: Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker! Are you running the above code from your local laptop or from within SageMaker Notebook Instance?

Answer (score 20):

You need to set the Region in the config file as asked by AWS documentation. You can find the location here:

```
~/.aws/config on Linux, macOS, or Unix

C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config on Windows
```

This file should contain lines in the following format:

```
[default]
region = your_aws_region
```

Example, in my case, it needs to be `region = ap-southeast-2`

Comment: why if it uses boto3 client under it, and boto3 is capable of using the environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` ?

I have the same problem and that environment variable is correctly set

Answer (score 6):

In my case I solved it by creating sagemaker session by doing this:

```
import boto3
import sagemaker

sagemaker.Session(boto3.session.Session())
```

and having the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable set as `us-east-1`.

Answer (score 5):

Continued to @Avi's answer.
In MacOS.
Should modify in `~/.aws/credentials`
with

```
[default]
region = <your_aws_region>
```

Answer (score 2):

This Python code is quite handy in certain scenarios where we don't have the option of defining a config file:

```
import os 
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = <YOUR_REGION>
```